# Can't post a new book/item to awesomebox.io scan page, wrong payload

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I'm having problems to post a new book/item at http://www.awesomebox.io/scan
If I do it manually at the website it works. And I see the post request, with a status 200

But with my python script im getting a status 400.

Anyone has a idea/solution or a working code example?
Wrong payload? or do i need the javascript to post/add a new book/item???

My code so far:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import re

# Make session
session = requests.session()

# Define login page
loginURL = 'http://www.awesomebox.io/login'

# Get login page and build tree
loginpage = session.get(loginURL)

# Get the csrfmiddlewaretoken value from the login page
m = re.search('(?<=value=\')\w+', loginpage.text)
token = m.group(0)

# Post the payload to login in.
payload = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token , 'username': '******','password': '******'}
login = session.post(loginURL, data=payload)

# Session is now logged in, try to post/add a new book.
# Also manually possible at http://www.awesomebox.io/scan
additem = 'http://www.awesomebox.io/services/new-item/'
payload2 = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token ,'barcode': '9780321884916','branch': 'main' }

# Post the payload to add a new item/book
itempost = session.post(additem, data=payload)
print itempost.status_code
```

Comment: which call is returning 400?

Comment: print itempost.status_code

Comment: I do not think that "print itempost.status_code" can return 400. It is not a call... The error can be where @Friek is suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted 'payload' twice. You should post 'payload2' the second time if you'd like that to be posted ;)